# How to wrap <li> elements inside a <ul> tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

My html

```
<div class="note">
  <div class="fielditem">
   test one<br>
   test two
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery to wrap each line with li which is working well.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var listHTML = $('.note .fielditem').html();
  if (listHTML !== undefined && listHTML !== null) {
  var listItems = listHTML.split('<br>');
  $('.note .fielditem').html('');
  $.each(listItems, function(i, v) {
    var item = '<li>' + v + '</li>';
    $('.note .fielditem').append(item);
  });
 }
});
```

Now i want to insert ul tag around all the li items, like this

```
<div class="note">
  <div class="fielditem">
   <ul>
    <li>test one</li>
    <li>test two</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried searching but couldn't come up with relevant answers. Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var listHTML = $('.note .fielditem').html();
  if (listHTML !== undefined && listHTML !== null) {
    var listItems = listHTML.split('<br>');
    $('.note .fielditem').html('');
    $.each(listItems, function(i, v) {
      var item = '<li>' + v + '</li>';
      $('.note .fielditem').append(item);
    });
    $('.note .fielditem li').wrapAll('<ul>');
  }
});
```

This will select all the `<li>` elements inside the .`fielditem` div, and wrap them all in a `<ul>` tag using the `.wrapAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Ans1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   var listHTML = $(".note .fielditem").html();
   var elementList = $(".note .fielditem");
   if (listHTML !== undefined && listHTML !== null) {
     var listItems = listHTML.split("<br>");
     $(".note .fielditem").html("");

     let my_ul = $("<ul>");
     $.each(listItems, function (i, v) {
       my_ul.append($("<li>").append(v));
     });
     elementList.append(my_ul);
    }
});
```

Ans2:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var listHTML = $(".note .fielditem").html();
  var elementList = $(".note .fielditem");
  if (listHTML !== undefined && listHTML !== null) {
    var listItems = listHTML.split("<br>");
    $(".note .fielditem").html("");

    let my_ul_list = "<ul>";
     $.each(listItems, function (i, v) {
     my_ul_list += "<li>"+v+"</li>"
     });
     my_ul_list += "</ul>"
     elementList.html(my_ul_list) 
   }
});
```